# How to use pandas extract method for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe that has price data but puts it all together as "price x size (num_orders)". For example, the column (as read in from CSV file) is:
127.3 x 13 (1)
I came across the Pandas extract method and I have it working, but I am only able to make it work for creating one column and a time. So I have it working, but I want to know how to do it all in one statement as I think that it will, at least, give me a bit of Pandas instruction.
This works:

```
df['price']=df.Level1.str.extract('(\d*\.\d*) x', expand=False)
df['size']=df.Level1.str.extract(' x (\d*)', expand=False)
df['num_orders'] = df.Level1.str.extract(' \((\d*)\)$', expand=False)
```

but this does NOT:

```
gcq7['price'], gcq7['size'], gcq7['num_orders'] = 
gcq7.Level1.str.extract('(?P<price>\d*\.\d*) x (?P<size>\d*) \((?P<num_orders>\d*)\)$', expand=False)
```

I just get three columns that are titled correctly (price, size, num_orders) but have their column names as values all the way down, i.e., the 'price' column has "price" as the value for every row.

Help appreciated.

Edit:
consider the following column with index as input:

```
Date_Timestamp
2017-06-01 00:00:00.000      127.06000000 x 8 (0)
2017-06-01 00:00:00.000      127.38000000 x 8 (0)
```

And desired output:

```
                              price     size    num_orders
Date_Timestamp          
2017-06-01 00:00:00.000     127.06000000    8   0
2017-06-01 00:00:00.000     127.38000000    8   0
```

Edited per suggestion and for future clarity.

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected outputs to this question.  It will help us help you better.

Comment: @ScottBoston you are correct. I thought it would be clear the way I wrote it, but would have been easier. Thankfully some answered anyway.

Comment: @ScottBoston edited as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you were almost there:

```
pat = r'(?P<price>\d*\.\d*)\s*x\s*(?P<size>\d*)\s*\((?P<num_orders>\d*)\)$'
gcq7[['price','size','num_orders']] = gcq7.Level1.str.extract(pat, expand=True)
# NOTE:                                                                   ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that solving it was simply a matter of using gcq7[['price','size','num_orders']] = ..., rather than gcq7['price'], gcq7['size'], gcq7['num_orders'] = ...  It works with either expand=True or expand=False.

Comment: @kdragger, thanks for the update! I wasn't sure how would it work with `expand=False`...

Comment: Anyone able to explain why this worked but the "comma" assignment did not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use extractall

Consider this df:

```
gcq7 = pd.DataFrame({'Level1': ['127.3 x 13 (1)']})

gcq7.Level1.str.extractall('(?P<price>.*) x (?P<size>\d*) \((?P<num_orders>\d*)\)')\
.reset_index(drop=True)
```

You get

```
    price   size    num_orders
0   127.3   13      1
```

Comment: Thanks @Vaishali. This does not solve my problem. I want the new columns to be part of the existing df. Which means I need the index (so can't drop it). Also, thx for pointing out extractall, but it sets up a multiindex which also does not solve the problem.